# Redux, rollback state to a specific point

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been looking through the documentation but cannot find any references to this..  Does Redux by default have built in functionality that allows us to reference the current version of state and roll back to that reference down the line?

Comment: You can do this with the Redux Dev Tools, but I don't know of a way to do it programatically without tracking the state changes yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Redux has very minimal built-in functionality, but [was designed to be extended for use cases like undo/redo](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/09/presentation-might-need-redux-ecosystem/).  There are [numerous existing libraries specifically for undo/redo](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/use-cases.md#undo-redo), and I would guess that some of those would be useful for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just looked through the source code and the only available methods are:

- dispatch
- subscribe
- getState
- replaceReducer
- [$$observable]: observable

So I guess it's not possible... Shame..

Answer (score 0):

Redux is not a framework with lot of popular cases and solutions, it is state container with simple concepts. 
According to redux [documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ImplementingUndoHistory.html), you should implement undo/redo functionality in your program manually with list of past, present and future stack.

Comment: I am aware of undo/redo but it has performance hits! I'm working with a massive object state.  It also has a lot of overhead functionality that is not needed..